# Pergunta Múltipla escolha

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho que desenvolver um quiz com javascript, a primeira parte já desenvolvi que são para pegar a resposta de perguntas com apenas 1 resposta correta, mas não estou conseguindo fazer a segunda parte que são as perguntas com mais de uma resposta correta, pensei em utilizar o checkbox, mas não funcionou,vou colocar o código que fiz para uma resposta correta

```
<p><input type="radio" name="questao" value="A">resposta 1</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="questao" value="B">resposta 2</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="questao" value="C">resposta 3</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="questao" value="D">resposta 4</p>
<p id="mensagem"></p>

var resposta = "D"; // Resposta correta
$("input[name=questao]").on("click", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var mensagem = "";
    resposta == value ? mensagem = "Parabéns, Acertou!" : mensagem = "Resposta errada, tente novamente";
    $("#mensagem").html("<strong>" + mensagem + "</strong>");
});
```

Comment: você quer poder selecionar mais de uma opção? ou apenas permitir que seja escolhido uma das respostas corretas?

Comment: Se são mais de uma resposta correta, você **deverá** utilizar o *checkbox*. Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar como fez com esses elementos para entendermos o porquê de não ter funcionado?

Comment: Poder selecionar mais de uma opção e na hora já aparecer se está certo ou errado a resposta

Comment: @Thi100 tente postar mais informações do seu código

Comment: @Thi100 Poseti um código utilizando checkbox para resolver o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mais uma opção

```js
let respostasCorretas = ["D", "A"];

$("#btnConfirmar").on("click", function() {

  let selecionadas = $("input[name='questao']:checked");
  let corretas = 0

  $("input[name='questao']").attr('disabled', 'disabled')

  $.each(selecionadas, function() {
    let resposta = $(this);

    if (respostasCorretas.includes(resposta.val())) {
      resposta.closest('p').addClass('correta');
      corretas++;
    } else {
      resposta.closest('p').addClass('errada');
    }

  });
  let mensagem = "";

  if (corretas == 0)
    mensagem = "Você errou todas as alternativas"
  else if (corretas > 0)
    mensagem = "Você acertou epenas " + corretas + " das alternativas.";

  if (corretas == respostasCorretas.length)
    mensagem = "Parabéns, você acertou todas as alternativas";

  $("#mensagem").html(mensagem);
  $(this).addClass('escondido');
  $("#btnReset").removeClass('escondido');
  $("#mensagem").removeClass('escondido');
});

$("#btnReset").on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('escondido');
  $('p').removeClass('correta');
  $('p').removeClass('errada');
  $("input[name='questao']").removeAttr('disabled');
  $("input[name='questao']").prop('checked', false);
  $("#btnConfirmar").removeClass('escondido');
  $("#mensagem").toggleClass('escondido');
  

});
```

```css
.correta {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.errada {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#mensagem {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.escondido {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4> Selecione as duas alternativas corretas:</h4>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="A"> resposta 1</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="B"> resposta 2</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="C"> resposta 3</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="D"> resposta 4</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" id="btnConfirmar" value="Confirmar Resposta" />
  <input type="button" id="btnReset" class="escondido" value="Tentar Novamente" />
</p>
<p id="mensagem"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Acho que o mais indicado aí seria utilizar **radio** e usar um `if/else` e pegar as duas respostas que forem certas:

```js
$("input[name=questao]").on("click", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  if(value == 'A' || value == 'D') {
    $("#mensagem").text("Parabéns, Acertou!");
  }
  else {
    $("#mensagem").text("Resposta errada, tente novamente");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><input type="radio" name="questao" value="A">resposta 1</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="questao" value="B">resposta 2</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="questao" value="C">resposta 3</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="questao" value="D">resposta 4</p>
<p id="mensagem"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer desta forma, que inclusive servirá tanto para radio quanto para checkbox. Só precisa colocar as opções certas em ordem alfabética na variável `resposta` quando for checkbox com mais de uma opção correta. Por exemplo, se as opções corretas forem A e D: `var resposta = "AD";`

```js
var resposta = "AD"; // Respostas corretas
$("input[name=questao]").on("click", function() {
    var value = "";
    // seleciona apenas o que foi checado
    var resps = $("input[name=questao]:checked");
    if(resps.length){
       
       resps.each(function(){
          // concatena os values
          value += $(this).val();
       });
       
       var mensagem = "";
       resposta == value ? mensagem = "Parabéns, Acertou!" : mensagem = "Resposta errada, tente novamente";
       $("#mensagem").html("<strong>" + mensagem + "</strong>");
    }else{
       // esvazia a div de mensagem
       $("#mensagem").empty();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Opções corretas: A e D
<p>A) <input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="A">resposta 1</p>
<p>B) <input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="B">resposta 2</p>
<p>C) <input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="C">resposta 3</p>
<p>D) <input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="D">resposta 4</p>
<p id="mensagem"></p>
```

Usando radio com o mesmo script acima:

```js
var resposta = "D"; // Respostas corretas
$("input[name=questao]").on("click", function() {
    var value = "";
    // seleciona apenas o que foi checado
    var resps = $("input[name=questao]:checked");
    if(resps.length){
       
       resps.each(function(){
          // concatena os values
          value += $(this).val();
       });
       
       var mensagem = "";
       resposta == value ? mensagem = "Parabéns, Acertou!" : mensagem = "Resposta errada, tente novamente";
       $("#mensagem").html("<strong>" + mensagem + "</strong>");
    }else{
       // esvazia a div de mensagem
       $("#mensagem").empty();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Resposta correta: D
<p>A) <input type="radio" name="questao" value="A">resposta 1</p>
<p>B) <input type="radio" name="questao" value="B">resposta 2</p>
<p>C) <input type="radio" name="questao" value="C">resposta 3</p>
<p>D) <input type="radio" name="questao" value="D">resposta 4</p>
<p id="mensagem"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que exista um erro em como você esta utilizando o operador ternário:

```
  resposta == value ? mensagem = "Parabéns, Acertou!" : mensagem = "Resposta errada, tente novamente";
```

Tente trocar isso para:

```
  mesagem = resposta == value ? 'Parabéns, Acertou!' : 'Resposta errada, tente novamente';
```

Além disso, vocẽ deverá usar `<input type='checkbox'>` para multipla escolha, e para as respostas certas, voce pode usar um array, seu HTML pode ser assim:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="A">resposta 1</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="B">resposta 2</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="C">resposta 3</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="questao" value="D">resposta 4</p>

<p id="mensagem"></p>
```

Com isso, seu JS pode mudar para:

```
var respostasCertas = ['A', 'D'];
var respostasEscolhidas = [];
$('input[name="questao"]').on('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        respostasEscolhidas.push($(this).val());
    } else {
        removeA(respostasEscolhidas, $(this).val());
    }
});

function removeA(arr) {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            arr.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Acima, utilizo uma função de outra pergunta, para [remover posição do array pelo valor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/how-to-remove-item-from-array-by-value)

Para checkar a resposta voce pode adicioar um `<a>` ou um `submit`

```
<a onclick="checkResponse()">Checar resposta</a>
```

E, finalmente, criar uma função que checa a resposta:

```
 function checkResponse() {
    if (respostasCertas.length === respostasEscolhidas.length && respostasCertas.sort().every(function(value, index) { return value === respostasEscolhidas.sort()[index]})) {
        $('#mensagem').text('VOCE ACERTOU');
    } else {
        $('#mensagem').text('TENTE NOVAMENTE');
    }

}
```

A função acima, foi retirada [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Testei esse código e acho que é exatamente o que procura, espero ter ajudado!